# jquery validation not working in IE8 and below

Tags: jquery, validation

Hi I am using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0 to validate my registration form.but somehow in IE8 and below validation method is not getting fire and form direct gets submitted, also i am not able to see errors. below is my code,

Help will be most appreciated.

```
$("#frmfreeregister").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {required:true,email:true},
            txtpwd: {required:true,minlength:3},
            txtrepwd: {required:true,minlength:3,equalTo:"#password"},
            uname: {required:true,letterswithbasicpunc:true},
            designation: {required:true},
            mobile: {NumbersOnly:true,maxlength:15},
            company: {required:true},
            address: {required:true,letterswithbasicpunc:true},
            phone: {required:true,NumbersOnly:true,maxlength:15},
            fax: {NumbersOnly:true,maxlength:15},
            website:{complete_url:true},
            cid:{required:true,ValidCountry:true},
            about:{letterswithbasicpunc:true}
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.email'); ?>",
                email:"<?php echo lang('error.email'); ?>"
            },
            txtpwd: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.password'); ?>",
                minlength:"<?php echo lang('error.minlength.password'); ?>"
            },
            txtrepwd: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.password'); ?>",
                minlength:"<?php echo lang('error.minlength.password'); ?>",
                equalTo: "<?php echo lang('error.equalTo.password'); ?>"
            },
            uname: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.name'); ?>",
                letterswithbasicpunc: "<?php echo lang('error.letterswithbasicpunc'); ?>"
            },
            designation: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.designation'); ?>"
            },
            mobile: {
                NumbersOnly:"<?php echo lang('error.NumbersOnly'); ?>",
                maxlength:"<?php echo lang('error.maxlength15'); ?>"
            },
            company: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.company'); ?>"
            },
            address: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.companyAddress'); ?>",
                letterswithbasicpunc:"<?php echo lang('error.letterswithbasicpunc'); ?>"
            },
            phone: {
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.phone'); ?>",
                NumbersOnly:"<?php echo lang('error.NumbersOnly'); ?>",
                maxlength:"<?php echo lang('error.maxlength15'); ?>"
            },
            fax: {
                NumbersOnly:"<?php echo lang('error.NumbersOnly'); ?>",
                maxlength:"<?php echo lang('error.maxlength15'); ?>"
            },
            website:{
                complete_url:"<?php echo lang('error.complete_url'); ?>"
            },
            cid:{
                required:"<?php echo lang('error.required.Country'); ?>",
                ValidCountry:"<?php echo lang('error.ValidCountry'); ?>"
            },
            about:{
                letterswithbasicpunc:"<?php echo lang('error.letterswithbasicpunc'); ?>"
            }
        },
        success: function(label) {  
            label.addClass("success");
        },
        submitHandler: function(frmfreeregister) {
            Submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the on form submit to include something like this...

```
if($("#submitForm").valid()) {
       document.forms["submitForm"].submit();
}
```